# Can't fix NoClassDefFound error in Java

Tags: java, swing, applet, noclassdeffounderror, japplet

I build project in eclipse - swing applet and now I'm trying to run it in a browser.

I have 3 packages, let's say they are called: "pkgApplet", "pkgFirst", "pkgSecond" with .class files. In pkgApplet I have class "main" with method `main()`. No matter what I do, I can't run this applet in browser. Currently my html code looks like this

```
<applet code="bin/pkgApplet/main" height="1000" width="1000"/>
```

Browser gives this error every time no matter how I modify applet tag:

```
NoClassDefFoundError with message bin/pkgApplet/main(wrong name: applet/main)
```

I tried using `codebase` attribute, packing applet into .jar file and using `archive` attribute, but nothing seems to work. Do you have any idea what am I doing wrong?

Comment: if the package is called `pkgApplet`, what are the classes called?

Comment: `wrong name: applet/main` This indicate that `main.java` declares `package applet;`.  Is that correct?  *"I tried .. but nothing seems to work."*  Unfortunately, the only thing that works is understanding the nature of the parameters and paths.  I suspect you are a long way from that.  Just out of curiosity, why an applet at all?  Something in a frame is much easier(1) to develop and deploy on/from the net.  1) It won't change the need to understand packages, paths and class-paths, but will still be simpler.

Comment: Sorry. I've been messing with names of packages and I forget to change its name in output. There should be "wrong name: pkgApplet/main".

Comment: `<applet code="bin/pkgApplet/main" height="1000" width="1000"/>` Is invalid in any HTML version.  Back in 3.2 (last time `applet` was a valid element), it had to be explicitly closed.  E.G.  `<applet code="bin/pkgApplet/main" height="1000" width="1000"></applet>`, or as @Reimeus already mentioned, `bin.pkgApplet.main` (a `.` instead of `/`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your applet format should be:

```
<applet codebase="bin" code="pkgApplet.main" height="1000" width="1000"></applet>
```

`bin` is the default target directory (for Eclipse) so will require the codebase attribute as shown above. For this to work, your `HTML` file needs to be located in your project directory.

Note classes in Java start with uppercase, while package names are lowercase. Also its helpful to name classes describing what they do. You could have instead:

```
<applet codebase="bin" code="pkgapplet.MyMainApplet" height="1000" width="1000"></applet>
```

Do you realize that nothing in `main` will be called by your applet client? Any startup functionality should be placed in the `init` method.

Comment: +1 but the default target directory is where the HTML was loaded from.

Comment: Ok, updated but unlikely to be the final codebase when deployed :)

Comment: Thank you. It helped. I realized that I managed to write correct applet tag before. Currently, applet gives me InvocationTargetException, which means it found way to method main, but there is some other error, which I probably considered(without displaying error) to be same in my previous attempts.